# Detecting touches on a UISlider?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a UISlider on screen, and I need to be able to detect when the user stops touching it. (so I can fade some elements away).

I have tried using:

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

but this did not work when ending touches on a slider.

Comment: Why not use a target+action with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`?

Comment: This is a great suggestion! I wasn't aware you could use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` on a UISlider, but it works! :)

Answer (score 21):

You can detect when a touch ends using two control events; try

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) 
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

#### or

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) 
                       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

If you want to detect both types of the `touchesEnd` event, use

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `touchesEnded:` (which shouldn't be used for this purpose anyway), attach an action to the `UISlider`'s `UIControlEventValueChanged` event and set the `continuous` property of the `UISlider` to `NO`, so the event will fire when the user finishes selecting a value.

```
mySlider.continuous = NO;
[mySlider addTarget:self
          action:@selector(myMethodThatFadesObjects) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: It's a nice idea that works, but I was already using `UIControlEventValueChanged` to get live updates on where the UISlider was, so I couldn't do that if I set `continuous` to no.

Comment: So you want to get the value in realtime, but only apply that value when the user stops touching it? That should have been stated in your question.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get anything to capture both the start and end of the touches, but upon RTFD-ing, I came up with something that will do both.

```
  @IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: UISlider, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
      switch touchEvent.phase {
      case .began:
        print("touches began")
        sliderTouchBegan()
      case .ended:
        print("touches ended")
        sliderTouchEnded()
      default:
        delegate?.sliderValueUpdated(sender.value)
      }
    }
  }
```

`sliderTouchBegan()` and `sliderTouchEnded()` are just methods I wrote that handle animations when the touch begins and when it ends. If it's not a begin or end, it's a `default` and the slider value updates.

Comment: Which control event type are u using for the sliderAction() ? Is it UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents?

Comment: @Hamed When you drag out the connection from the storyboard, make it an action and under arguments, make sure you specify sender AND (emphasis mine) event.