# IOS- slider react only when touchesEnded

Tags: ios, uislider

i m new with iOS, and i want to know how to make my slider to react **only** when the the touch is ended.
i figure that out with the method:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But i can't make it work.

Does anyone can help me with simple & clear example?

**Please, answer programmatically, i don't use storyBoard.**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add gesture recognizer:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSliderTap:)] autorelease];
 [slider addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

- (void)onSliderTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer { 
   // handle event
}
```

or add some action on slider:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `-Outside` instead of `-ValueChanged` (if you're doing that right now).

**Edit**: or, al little more elegant I would say, use `UIControlEventValueChanged`, but also have the event provided as a parameter to your method:

`[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(handleValueChanged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

And then check the phase of the touch, to see if it's in the `ended` state.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

these guys helped me alot: [Detecting touches on a UISlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971154/detecting-touches-on-a-uislider)

with a small accuracy:

the action for the relevant slider assign to him as:

```
[self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnded:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

and the method signature is:

```
- (IBAction)touchEnded:(id) sender
```

with storyboard it seems to me a bit different to assign the action to the slider.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property continuous.

Contains a Boolean value indicating whether changes in the sliders value generate continuous update events.

```
mySlider.continuous= NO;
```