# How to code of UITableview detailtextLabel value dynamically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uislider

i want to code of UISlider Value Changed that time also UItableview detailTextLabel Value also be changed? see below Image.

[image]

when i am change slider value dynamically change of detailTextLabel of Alert Range ?
also store when i am come back with this UIview that also represent old value of slider and detailTextLabel.

```
 UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 45, 290,20)];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSString *sliderValue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d KM",(int)[_defaults floatForKey:@"Slider"]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = sliderValue;
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {

        slider.minimumValue = 5;
        slider.maximumValue = 20;
        slider.value =(int)[_defaults floatForKey:@"Slider"];
        cell.accessoryView = slider;

    }
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//[_table reloadData];
return cell; }

-(void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
 {
UISlider *slider = sender;
[_defaults setFloat:slider.value forKey:@"Slider"];
//[_table reloadData];
 }
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You want the range value to change as you move the slider and also save that value for when the user comes back to this screen ?

Comment: yes right !! @CW0007007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `[self.tableView reloadData];` each time the slider moves. 
Ensure the value you want to be dynamic is a property and is set by the slider.

If you do not want to reload the entire tableView you can also reload the cell with this function:

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Check out this question for more help on reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [Reload specific UITableView cell in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040740/reload-spefic-uitableview-cell-ios)

Comment: Come on, just think about it yourself, is it a good decision or not? Sorry for being harsh but I don't think it's a very good way of solving the problem at hand.

Comment: Just reload that one cell and not the whole table view.

Comment: what the solution for this question without reloading a table?
@SergiusGee

Comment: The selected solution is great now that you don't have to reload the entire `UITableView`. Good choice. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addTarget` for your `UISlider`. Everytime the `events` will be called, you can change the value inside your data model and `reloadTable` to show the changed value.

[Have a look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971390/1141395)